# How to get the value of input field in one page and print it in another page?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the value of an input field and print it on another HTML page? Here is my first page:

index.html

```
<form action="page.html" method="get">
<label>Enter your name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var name = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
</script>
```

I want to print that "name" variable on the "page.html". Please help.

Comment: HTML does not maintain state. So you will need to store the value in a cookie or local storage.

Comment: There are _lots_ of ways to do this. The best technique depends on the specifics of your situation. Are you needing this value to stick around just for the user of the browser? Just within the session? Permanently for the user no matter where they log in from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use localStorage , set this value :

```
localStorage.setItem('nameOfVariable', value);
```

and after loading other page you can get the value with

```
localStorage.getItem('nameOfVariable')
```

In your case :

```
function setName() {
   var name = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
   localStorage.setItem('name', name);
}
```

in page.html :

```
function getName() {
       var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
       // Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `localStorage`.

```
var name = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
window.localStorage.setItem('name', name);
```

And then in page.html page,

Try to get name

```
const name = window.localStorage.getItem('name')
```

And then print it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **localStorage** in the variable name like

```
document.getElementById("firstName").value = localStorage.name
```

You can acces the localStorage data from an another page like

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = localStorage.name;
```